# Can someone show me how I can output hrs:mins:secs in mySQL SELECT statement below?

Tags: mysql-workbench, dateadd

[Here is the picture of how I would like it to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsu8k.png)

Here is what I have so far when use the `DATE_ADD` function in `MySQL Workbench 6.3`, but I have been struggling to output the hrs:mins:secs (you don't see the code for that output because I didn't write it here). I know that I can use INTERVAL HOUR_SECOND to display hrs:mins:secs but I don't understand how it works.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 31 DAY) AS '31 Days';
```

I know this `SELECT statement` above will output 31 days from the specified date indicated above, but what do I need to do to output the hrs:mins:secs along with the 31 days from the date in the `SELECT statement`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `DATE_FORMAT()`. Examples:

Add function

```
/*
* Adds a particular interval to given date
*/
SELECT DATE_ADD('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 31 DAY) AS '31 Days';
```

Output:

```
31 Days
2017-02-26
```

Format function

```
/*
* Formats a particular date object
*/
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')
AS 'Now';
```

Output:

```
Now
Jan 28 2017 04:29 PM
```

Format and add:

```
/*
* Adds and Formats date object
*/
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 31 DAY),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')
AS 'Formatted date';
```

Output:

```
Formatted date
Feb 26 2017 12:00 AM
```

Additionally, here is the sqlfiddle for the example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/92948

Also check the various formats to further tailor to your needs: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: I have to use date_add function because I want to know how that function works only.

Comment: Can you show me how I would do what I want with that function only?

Comment: Can you please add an example how you want the output?

Comment: The picture is uploaded for how I would like it displayed. The hrs:mins:secs that you see don't correspond to the 31 days after indicated date. It corresponds to current time of the date indicated in SELECT statement.

Comment: edited for an explanation and query specific to your needs